# How do I find the corner points of the feasible region for a system of linear inequalities [R]?

Tags: r, linear-programming

My system has only two variables, and I want to plot the polygon in a custom 2D plot.

I suppose it's very tightly connected with linear programming, so I checked the `lpSolve` package, but there is no way:

- not to enter the objective function
- not to run the optimization
- to retrieve the corner points. I'm not sure if the solver calculates them all anyways.

There is also a method `solve2dlp` in the package `intpoint` that actually plots something alike, but somehow I cannot get through the code to check what exactly is it doing..

Comment: If you want to see the source code something, submit `<package>:::<object>`. In this case it would be `intpoint:::solve2dlp`.

Comment: I've seen the code, but it's kinda illegible (at least to me). Additionally I'm new to LP, so I have no idea if it's doing the thing I really need. But thanks for the `:::` tip - the code is at least indented, I was reading the source package, where it looks like old Fortran without any indents...